# How to read $\langle ~\rangle$ in $\langle F(a) | a \in A \rangle$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In Hrbacek and Jeck's book, *Introduction to set theory*, the symbol $\langle~\rangle$ is introduced for function representations.

I can read $F:A \rightarrow B$, however, I can't read $\langle F(a) | a \in A \rangle $, 
$\langle F_a | a \in A \rangle$, $\langle F_a \rangle _{a\in A}$.

There are some examples:

$\langle 2x-1 ~|~ x ~~ real \rangle$,

$\langle x^2 ~ |~ x ~~ real \rangle$,

$\langle \frac{1}{x} ~|~ x~~real, ~~x \neq 0 \rangle$.

Each of $2x-1$, $x^2$, and  $\frac{1}{x}$  is not element of set. It is some value of a function.

In the second example, when $x=1$ or $x=-1$, the value of $x^2$ are both $1$.

Can I read the second example as *"the collection of all $x$ squared such that x is real"*?

Comment: I don't think it's something you should read on its own. It's part of a larger notation, just like "$\frac{\phantom1}{\phantom 2}$" isn't anything on its own but rather part of "$\frac12$".

Comment: @Arthur then, can I omit $<>$ when pronouncing these phrases?

Comment: Oh, you mean "read" like that. Then no, I don't think so. You can't omit $\{\}$ when talking about, say, $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid x=2y,y\in \Bbb N\}$, but have to read them as "the set of".

Comment: It is simply a notation for "naming" functions (see page 24). Thus, it must be read : "the function $F$ with domain $A$".

Comment: The collection of all $F_a$ indexed by a in A?

Comment: Isn't it $\langle F(a)|a\in A\rangle$ rather than $<F(a)|a\in A>$?

Comment: @bof I think you are right. how to type your braket in tex?

Comment: \$\langle\rangle\$

Comment: If you right-click on an expression you can see the tex code.